# How can I differentiate between 0 and whitespace in Perl?

Tags: perl, whitespace

I have the following piece of code in my program:

```
$val = chr(someFunction());

if($val == " ")
{
    #do something

}
elsif($val == 0)
{
   #do something else
}
```

But whenever 0 is passed to $val, the if part executes instead of the elsif which I expect to get executed.

How can I fix this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 23):

The `==` operator is used to compare numeric values. If you want to compare strings, you should use the `eq` operator.

```
if ($val eq " ") ...
```

Comment: Also, are you sure that you want to test whether $val is exactly one space character? If you want the first branch of your "if" statement to execute whenever $val contains one or more spaces, use a regex instead.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to fix this ([TIMTOWDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_is_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)).  You could import the `looks_like_a_number` function from the standard `Scalar::Util` package:

```
if (looks_like_a_number($val) and $val == 0) {
    #do something
}
```

You could use the string equality operator

```
if ($val eq 0) {
    #do something
}
```

If you have Perl 5.10, you could use the smart match operator

```
if ($val ~~ 0) {
    #do something
}
```

And many more.  Which method you use depends heavily on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

If you had warnings enabled, you would have known what the problem was.

Run this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $val = chr(someFunction());

if($val == " ")
{
    #do something

}
elsif($val == 0)
{
   #do something else
}

sub someFunction {
    return 1;
}
```

And you get:
C:>test.pl
Argument " " isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at C:\test.pl line 6.
Argument "^A" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at C:\test.pl line 6.

Adding use diagnostics gives us this additional explanation:

```
   (W numeric) The indicated string was fed as an argument to an operator
   that expected a numeric value instead.  If you're fortunate the message
   will identify which operator was so unfortunate.
```

So, since we don't want numeric eq, we want string eq: `eq`.  If you didn't know that already, you could look in `perldoc perlop` to read about [Equality Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators).

This is a classic example of how using the `warnings` and `strict` pragmas saves time.